# Compilation errors when including <regex> using Clang 3.x with --std=c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, clang, ubuntu-16.04

I've been trying to compile the [Catch2](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2) header as part of a larger existing project where I used to rely on googletest. I've been able to get the port working nicely on Windows, but I'm struggling to get the library compiled on Ubuntu using Clang. I've tested versions 3.5 through 3.7.

I've included the errors generated at compile time:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/catch/catch.hpp:7932:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-
gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/regex:61:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-
gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/bits/regex.h:2796:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-
gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/bits/regex.tcc:102:16: error: 
expected unqualified-id
          auto& __pre = __m._M_prefix();
                  ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-
gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/bits/regex.tcc:106:13: error: 
expected expression
              __pre.matched = false;
                   ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-
gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/bits/regex.tcc:107:13: error: 
expected expression
              __pre.first = __s;
                   ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-
gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/bits/regex.tcc:108:13: error: 
expected expression
              __pre.second = __s;
                   ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-
gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/bits/regex.tcc:115:13: error: 
expected expression
              __pre.first = __s;
                   ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-
gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/bits/regex.tcc:116:13: error: 
expected expression
              __pre.second = __res[0].first;
                   ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-
gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/bits/regex.tcc:117:13: error: 
expected expression
              __pre.matched = (__pre.first != __pre.second);
                   ^
7 errors generated.
```

Let me know if there is any additional information I can include to help narrow down the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean `-std=c++11`?

Comment: Yes - thanks for the correction. While grasping for straws, I have since tried both `c++14` and `c++1z`, but without any success.

Comment: Try to compile the Catch2 library in isolation and check if you can see ["Enabling C++11"](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L317) message.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @AlvaroDenisAcosta. With a trivial compile command, I'm unable to tease out the error. Once I start specifying some of the include directories (using the `-I` flag), then the error surfaces again.

Comment: @Julius Let me know if I understand you, you are able to build the Ctach2 project on your system,  when you "start specifying some of the include directories" you can not build your project?
Can you share a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce this?

Comment: I was able to compile `catch2` in isolation (including it on a source file with a main entry point defined). Then I started passing the additional include directories from my existing project to the compiler one by one, until the solution failed to build again. It became clear that the issue is not in `catch2` or the compiler flags that I'm specifying for the build . To resolve the issue, I refactored the code so that the additional include directories are unnecessary for the test project. The root cause is still unclear, but your suggestion proved very helpful!